# Connect a Progress database using php and ODBC

Tags: php, jdbc, odbc, progress-db, datadirect

I am developing a project using PHP 7.3 for one of my customers. My app will need to connect to a Progress database. So far I am using DataDirect to do that. It is a free trial version. It uses an ODBC driver. https://www.progress.com/odbc

Do you know if there is another way to connect to a Progress database ? One free way ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Progress OpenEdge DB is a commercial product and the licensing is (usually, mostly) based on connections or users.  So, no there is no free way to connect and if your application is adding users or connections then the license auditing team at Progress will probably find that interesting.

However the ODBC drivers are free to properly licensed users with a current maintenance contract so you should be able to easily convert the trial to a full time license. Someone might need to contact Progress to get it available on the customer's download site.